# yalc "Could not find package <package) in store (/root/.yalc/packages)"

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, npm-publish

I have a local npm package that I have made changes to but when I try to add them to my consumer repo to test those changes using `yalc add <package>` I receive this message `Could not find package <package> in store (/root/.yalc/packages/package), skipping.`. When I run `yalc dir` it shows the store location of `/home/username/.yalc`. For the life of me I don't know why yalc is trying to add packages from root. Anyone ever encounter this?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it...my yarn `node_modules` was `sudo` for some reason. I deleted it then ran `yarn` again.